# What's the difference between the 5 Magical Record setup methods?

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, core-data, magicalrecord

Can anyone give a description of each of the 5 setup methods?

```
(void) setupCoreDataStack;
(void) setupAutoMigratingDefaultCoreDataStack;
(void) setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore;
(void) setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:(NSString *)storeName;
(void) setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:(NSString *)storeName;
```

What do they each do and what is the use case for each?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
setupCoreDataStack
```

Use this when you're just getting started with MagicalRecord. This will, as the method states, set up your default Core Data stack. The pieces of the stack are well know and comprise of: NSPersistentStore, NSPersistentStoreCoordinate, NSManagedObjectModel and a default NSManagedObjectContext. At least one of each of these must be instantiated and configured properly for Core Data to work. MagicalRecord provides this single method to configure your stack with a SQLite persistent store located in /Library/Application Support//.sqlite

```
setupAutoMigratingDefaultCoreDataStack
```

When you version your model, you will need to migrate your data. This method will do the same as the previous (above) method, but will also enable Auto Migrations.

```
setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore;
```

Sometimes, such as when you're writing unit tests, you want your data to go away when your app terminates. This method will also set up a CoreData stack (as mentioned above) but instead of a SQLite store, it creates a persistent store in system memory (RAM).

```
setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:(NSString *)storeName
```

Sometimes you want to customize the file name where your data resides. This method does the same as the first, namely setting up the core data stack, and placing a SQLite store in the specific location, but instead of .sqlite, the store is named storeName.sqlite

```
setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:(NSString *)storeName
```

This does the same as the above method, but also enabled auto migrations. You'll need to do this when you version your model and have a simple migration that simply needs to be enabled.

You can read more on Core Data migrations on [Apple's Core Data Reference Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)

Comment: How do you associate a xcdatamodeld file to MagicalRecord? Will MagicalRecord respect xcdatamodeld attributes such as "Store in External Record File"?

Comment: By default, MagicalRecord will use the mergedModelsFromBundle: method with a nil parameter. This is also in the (horrible) boilerplate code provided by Xcode. This automatically figures it out for you. There are additional helpers to specify a model file when needed (unit testing is another common place where this is necessary)

Comment: I'm still a little confused... mergedModelsFromBundle will automatically scan the project structure for xcdatamodeld files? What happens if you have more than one xcdatamodeld? Do the entities (and their attributes) that you declare in those xcdatamodeld files need to match the NSManagedObjects that you subclass for MagicalRecord?

Comment: Also, is having a xcdatamodeld even neccesary with MagicalRecord? Can I set the "Store in External Record File" attribute just from NSManagedObject subclasses themselves?

Comment: The description is sparse, but the docs for NSManagedObjectModel tells you exactly what's going on, namely it knows how to find all the models in a bundle and merge them into a single model https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001174-BCIJICAH

Comment: xcdatamodeld is only there when you version your models, which I think Xcode does by default these days. So, yes